Pass data from getInitialProps to getServerSideProps
I'm developing a NextJS project and I'm fetching some necessary data in the getInitialProps of _app.js and setting it into cookies. However, I was wondering if there is any way to share this data with getServerSideProps of any page as for the first time I cannot access data from req.cookies in getServerSideProps.
_app.js

import cookies from 'js-cookie';
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

App.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
 const { req, res, query } = ctx;
  const data = await fetchSomeData();
  
  // Set data into cookies
  cookies.set('myData', data);

  return { ...appProps, data };
};

export default MyApp;


[...products].js
export async function getServerSideProps({ params, req, res, query }) {
const ids = // expecting data from intial props
const products = getProductByIds(ids)
  return {
    props: {
      products,
    },
  };
}

I want to access the data which was fetched in getInitialProps to proceed further to fetch products.

You can use global data
let store = {};

const globalStore = {};

globalStore.set = (key, value) => {

    store = { ...store, [key]: value };
}

globalStore.get = (key) => {
    return store[key];
}


export default globalStore;

And then in _app.js
App.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
    const { req, res, query } = ctx;
    const data = await fetchSomeData();

    // Set data into cookies
    cookies.set('myData', data);
  
    globalStore.set('ids_from_app', 'your ids here'); // set data here

    return { ...appProps, data };
};

in page.js
export async function getServerSideProps({ params, req, res, query }) {
    const ids = globalStore.get('ids_from_app'); // get data from globalStore
    const products = getProductByIds(ids)
    return {
        props: {
          products,
        },
    };
}

By the way, Don't forget to import globalStore
